# Lua - gmatch scientific notation string to number

Tags: string, lua, scientific-notation

I am trying to convert a string of scientific notation numbers into actual numbers.

My test string is formatted like so:

```
myString = 1.000000000000000E+00,  2.000000000000000E+02,  -1.000000000000000E+05
```

My current code:

```
elements = {}

for s in myString:gmatch('%d+%.?%d*') do
    table.insert(elements, s);
end

return unpack(elements);
```

Elements returns the following incorrectly:

```
1.000000000000000     %from the first number before "E"
00                    %after the "E" in the first number
2.000000000000000     %from the second number before "E"
```

Anyone know how I can go about fixing this?

Comment: `for s in myString:gmatch'[%d.eE+-]+' do`

Comment: Is `table.insert(myString, s);` just a typo or is that your actual code?

Comment: Just a typo when i copied parts over for this question :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, "actual numbers" means the number data type. `tonumber()` does quite well with scientific notation.

```
local myString = [[ 1.000000000000000E+00, 
 2.000000000000000E+02,  -1.000000000000000E+05 ]]
local function convert(csv)
    local list = {}
    for value in (csv .. ","):gmatch("(%S+)%W*,") do table.insert(list,tonumber(value)) end
    return unpack(list)
end
print(convert(myString))
```

Comment: This worked marvelously.  Thanks so much.  I'll have to remember "tonumber()" for the future!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
for s in (myString..","):gmatch("(%S+),") do print(s) end
```

Comment: That assumes that there are no errors in the string and that there's a space after the comma and no space before it.

Comment: @W.B., it does handle spaces after the comma but not before it. As for correctness of the input, the simplest thing is to run tonumber on each extracted string, as in Tom's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `gsplit` function defined here: [**SplitJoin**](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin), and then having a loop like so:

```
t = {}
for number in gsplit(myString:gsub('%s',''),',') do
    t[#t+1] = tonumber(number)
end
```

Which for a string:

```
myString = [[1.000000000000000E+00,  2.000000000000000E+02,  -1.000000000000000E+05]]
```

the result of `table.concat(t,',')` is:

```
1,200,-100000
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the pattern to recognize optional mantissa and use `tonumber` to get the number from the string:

```
elements = {}
myString = "1.000000000000000E+00,  2.000000000000000E+02,  -1.000000000000000E+05"
for s in myString:gmatch('[+%-]?%d+%.?%d*[eE+%-]*%d?%d?') do
    table.insert(elements, tonumber(s))
end
print(unpack(elements))
```

Comment: You forgot about possible sign in front: `[%+%-]?%d+%.?%d*[eE][%+%-]?%d+`. `[eE+%-]*` allows any number of all of those signs, whereas there could only be one E or e and `+-` is optional after that. And a number after E is mandatory.

Comment: Fixed; correct about [eE+%-]*, but there is no way to specify optional grouping using Lua patterns `([eE][-+]%d%d)?`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer, which is robust but probably overkill:

```
f = loadstring("return {" .. myString .."}")
if f==nil then  end -- myString malformed
elements = f()
```